# Will Deja Dup backup from multiple accounts?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Will Deja Dup backup data from two user accounts on the same Ubuntu 14.04
computer to an external disc? I have successfully backed up and restored
the main Administrator account but not a second user account.

Comment: @user68186: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: Each user has to run it themselves.

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW Done.

Comment: **DevonDave:**  Please don't thank **@user68186**!  **;-)** If the answer below did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of its text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**. I have three users including the admin. All gets backed up in an internal hard drive in separate folders.

Each user has to setup Deja Dup from their own account. Backup will only happen if and when the user is logged on.

I don't have any experience using Deja Dup with an external hard drive. You may have to make sure your other user has the read/write access to the backup folder of the external hard drive.

Hope this helps

Comment: You see?  Upvotes raining in already!  **;-)**